# Web Service in CI, PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, webservices-client

Hy, i have problem with my code. i use RESTful web service with CI Framework.

```
//model in Rest Server
public function ambil($semester, $matkul, $kelas){
    $this->db->select('mahasiswa.nama, mahasiswa.nim, k.grup');
    $this->db->from('mhs mahasiswa');
    $this->db->join('krs k', 'k.nim=mahasiswa.nim');
    $this->db->where(array('k.kmk'=>$matkul, 'k.grup'=>$kelas));
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array(); 
}

//controller in Rest Server
public function ambil_get(){
    $this->load->model('M_data');
    if(!$this->get('semester')){
        if (!$this->get('matkul')) {
            if (!$this->get('kelas')) {
                $this->response(NULL, 400);
            }
        }
    }

    $data = $this->M_data->ambil($this->get('semester','matkul','kelas'));
    if($data)
    {
        $this->response($data,200);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 404);
    }
}

//Controller in Client Server
public function getData(){
    $semester = $this->input->post('vsemester');
    $matkul = $this->input->post('vmatkul');
    $kelas = $this->input->post('vkelas');

    $data = $this->rest->get('ambil/semester/'.$semester.'/matkul/'.$matkul.'/kelas/'.$kelas.'', 'json');
    var_dump($data);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.($key+1).'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$value->nim.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$value->nama.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$value->grup.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
}
```

I'm using this code to call function ambil_get in controller of rest server but it doesn't work. Anybody knows why it doesn't work? And how to fix it? Thank you so much :)

Comment: sorry if my english isn't good.. but i really need help for this problem.. :)

Comment: any error or outputs there??

Comment: In model `print_r($query->result_array())` and post data.

Comment: i've tried compile this with bottom statement.. but error in model M_data..

http://localhost/sia/Rest_Server/ambil/semester/4/matkul/PAC342/kelas/A/format/json

Comment: undefined variable with matkul and kelas.. :(

Comment: in controller print this values and check whether variable is empty or not. `$semester` `$matkul` `$kelas`

Comment: so i print the variables on the rest controller or client controller??

Comment: try in both controllers

Comment: my model in array like this: $this->db->where(array('k.kmk'=>$matkul, 'k.grup'=>$kelas));

and i don't know how to call them in Rest Controller if I use $this->get.. :(

Comment: please anybody help me to solve this..